# How can I disable FTP access for users

Tags: linux, unix, centos

I want to temporarily disable the FTP Access of the **FTP users which are added from Cpanel**

I have tried 
`chsh -s /sbin/nologin aadmi` which says "chsh: user "aadmi" does not exist."

Tried
sudo `echo aadmi >> /etc/ftpusers` which added username in this file but no effect... Please note this file was not present before executing this command

I have Centos Server with Cpanel 11 installed with Pure-ftp installed

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask `root` to add the user names to `/etc/ftpusers`.

Without root access, you almost certainly don't have permission to make this change.

Comment: If you mean I need to use this command 'sudo echo aadmi >> /etc/ftpuser' then how can the user be reactivated?

Comment: If adding the username to that file deactivates FTP access, then removing the username from that file would reactivate FTP access.

Comment: I tried sudo echo aadmi >> /etc/ftpuser it added the username in ftpuser file but no change... the user aadmi still can login

Comment: The correct file name is `/etc/ftpusers`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Still no luck... My cpanel has pure-ftpd installed for managing ftp accounts